# MinGW C++: expected primary-expression before '/' token

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw32

This is my first question here, and the first time I haven't been able to find a solution to a C++ problem online by just looking around. I'm relatively inexperienced in this area, and am not sure what's relevant, so I'll just post whatever I think might be useful.

I'm using SDL to make a cross-platform application. I'm using MinGW 4.6.1 on Windows 7 (64-bit), as well as an Ubuntu setup on another computer.

It compiles fine on Ubuntu (using g++) without any complaints, but I get the following error when I try to compile on my Windows machine with g++:

```
...matrix.cpp:77:17: error: expected primary-expression before '/' token
...matrix.cpp:78:11: error: expected primary-expression before '/' token
...matrix.cpp:79:17: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
...matrix.cpp:79:28: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
...matrix.cpp:80:19: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
...matrix.cpp:80:30: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

As far as I can tell, there's nothing special in the function (especially since it compiles fine on my Ubuntu-setup):

```
Matrix *Matrix::projection(float near, float far, float top, float right) {
    x1 = near/right;
    y2 = near/top;
    z3 = -(far+near)/(far-near);
    z4 = -(2*far*near)/(far-near);
    w3 = -1.0;
    y1 = z1 = w1 =
    x2 = z2 = w2 =
    x3 = y3 =
    x4 = y4 = w4 = 0.0;
    return this;
}
```

In case it matters, here's the Matrix class:

```
class Matrix { // row-major matrix
    public:
        float x1, y1, z1, w1, x2, y2, z2, w2, x3, y3, z3, w3, x4, y4, z4, w4;
        Matrix();
        Matrix (float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f, float g, float h, float i, float j, float k, float l, float m, float n, float o, float p);
        Matrix (float *f);
        Matrix *identity();
        Matrix *translation(float x, float y, float z);
        Matrix *rotation(float a, float i, float j, float k);
        Matrix *rotation(Quaternion q);
        Matrix *projection(float near, float far, float top, float right);
        Matrix operator*(Matrix m);
        void operator*=(Matrix m);
        Matrix operator/(float f);
        void operator/=(float f);
        Matrix operator*(float f);
        void operator*=(float f);
        void operator=(float *f);
        float *getArray();
};
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to like the name 'near'; what happens if you rename it to something really innocuous (like nr)?

Comment: `g++ G:\JibbEngine\003\gameTest.exe G:\JibbEngine\003\gameTest.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -lOpenGL32 -lglu32` -- I compile it on Linux the same way, except with different libraries, of course, but an older version of my code worked on both so I don't think that could be a problem. I'm not using class headers atm (I know...), but I can't imagine how that'd get the compiler confused around the '/' operator. The .cpp file is definitely included in the right place and found by the compiler (hence the error).

Comment: @ScottHunter: Wow. Thanks. That fixed it. I can see how you deduced that it was the source of the problem, but do you have any idea why? -- also, what's common practice when one finds their answer in a comment rather than a list of submitted answers?

Comment: @Jibb : Mike's answer explains why, and was posted before Scott's comment. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn : Cheers -- I ticked Mike's as the "correct" answer (is there stackoverflow lingo for doing that?) since it does solve the issue.

Comment: @Jibb : Not that I'm aware of (re: lingo). But welcome to SO, and +1 for a well-prepared question. :-]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My wild guess is that `near` and/or `far` are defined as macros, possibly so that ancient 16-bit DOS/Windows code can be compiled.

Try adding `#undef near` and `#undef far` before your function and see if that helps.

Comment: This is almost certainly the case. `near` and `far` were pointer modifiers for 16 bit DOS/Windows that are probably still defined in the windows headers somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Mike! @ScottHunter's solution in the comments above ended up doing the trick, but this solves it too.